# The xml files not recognized by android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Here is my simple xml and android studio not recognize it and gave no suggestion when I try to write new line. It repeat in any new xml file in this project, but there is no such kind of errors in other my projects

Here is code.... Nothing so special, but if you will check the image, you will see that for example match parent in width property doesnt recogized at all, but put the text in proper way...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    tools:context=".NewActivity">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:text="Item Detail Here..."
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Comment: plz post completed xml file in text format

Answer (score 0):

Firstly check your layout xml file if there are errors.

Then try delete **.idea** folder of this project, reopen android studio and click `Build--Rebuild project` menu.

Comment: already tried... doesnt work. Also tried to Invalidate cache. Nothing

Answer (score 0):

First Check if Your Gradle sync...

After That Be sure if You do not have any error in import R or other packages

after That go to File>Invalidate Caches/Restart

and Build>Clean & Rebuild

It is ok for me :)

Comment: Already tried everything except R package...  How to check it?

Comment: You should Import it in activity for this layout ... Your package name.R like it ... Remove it after that click On R and Insert Alt+Enter and choose Import

Answer (score 0):

If we could see the whole xml file it will be more helpful, but here are things to try out.

- if there is more than one view inside that LinearLayout, then set an orientation for the LinearLayout, like so: `android:orientation="vertical"` or `android:orientation="horizontal"` for vertical or horizontal orientation.
- try invalidating the caches and rebuilding the project,  File>Invalidate Caches/Restart, then Build> Clean & Rebuild